# PyParsing simple language expressions

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to write something that will parse some code. I'm able to successfully parse `foo(spam)` and `spam+eggs`, but `foo(spam+eggs)` (recursive descent? my terminology from compilers is a bit rusty) fails.

I have the following code:

```
from pyparsing_py3 import *

myVal = Word(alphas+nums+'_')    
myFunction = myVal + '(' + delimitedList( myVal ) + ')'

myExpr = Forward()
mySubExpr = ( \
    myVal \
    | (Suppress('(') + Group(myExpr) + Suppress(')')) \
    | myFunction \
    )
myExpr << Group( mySubExpr + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ - / * =') + mySubExpr ) )


# SHOULD return: [blah, [foo, +, bar]]
# but actually returns: [blah]
print(myExpr.parseString('blah(foo+bar)'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several issues: delimitedList is looking for a comma-delimited list of myVal, i.e. identifiers, as the only acceptable form of argument list, so of course it can't match 'foo+bar' (not a comma-delimited list of myVal!); fixing that reveals another -- myVal and myFunction start the same way so their order in mySubExpr matters; fixing that reveals yet another -- TWO levels of nesting instead of one.  This versions seems ok...:

```
myVal = Word(alphas+nums+'_')    

myExpr = Forward()
mySubExpr = (
    (Suppress('(') + Group(myExpr) + Suppress(')'))
    | myVal + Suppress('(') + Group(delimitedList(myExpr)) + Suppress(')')
    | myVal
    )
myExpr << mySubExpr + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ - / * =') + mySubExpr ) 

print(myExpr.parseString('blah(foo+bar)'))
```

emits `['blah', ['foo', '+', 'bar']]` as desired.  I also removed the redundant backslashes, since logical line continuation occurs anyway within parentheses; they were innocuous but did hamper readability.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that a good habit to get into when using the '<<' operator with Forwards is to always enclose the RHS in parentheses.  That is:

```
myExpr << mySubExpr + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ - / * =') + mySubExpr )
```

is better as:

```
myExpr << ( mySubExpr + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ - / * =') + mySubExpr ) )
```

This is a result of my unfortunate choice of '<<' as the "insertion" operator for inserting the expression into a Forward.  The parentheses are unnecessary in this particular case, but in this one:

```
integer = Word(nums)
myExpr << mySubExpr + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ - / * =') + mySubExpr ) | integer
```

we see why I say "unfortunate".  If I simplify this to "A << B | C", we easily see that the precedence of operations causes evaluation to be performed as "(A << B) | C", since '<<' has higher precedence than '|'.  The result is that the Forward A only gets the expression B inserted in it.  The "| C" part does get executed, but what happens is that you get "A | C" which creates a MatchFirst object, which is then immediately discarded since it is not assigned to any variable name.  The solution would be to group the statement within parentheses as "A << (B | C)".  In expressions composed only using '+' operations, there is no actual need for the parentheses, since '+' has a higher precedence than '<<'.  But this is just lucky coding, and causes problem when someone later adds an alternative expression using '|' and doesn't realize the precedence implications.  So I suggest just adopting the style "A << (expression)" to help avoid this confusion.

(Someday I will write pyparsing 2.0 - which will allow me to break compatibilty with existing code - and change this to use the '<<=' operator, which fixes all of these precedence issues, since '<<=' has lower precedence than any of the other operators used by pyparsing.)

Comment: Paul,
That's very useful information on operator precedence that I hadn't considered. Thank you for that, and also thank you for a wonderful contribution to the Python community! I enjoyed 'Getting Started with Pyparsing', but I apparently need a bit more experience.